# How to concatenate two variables as strings?

Tags: javascript

I have searched a lot but it is not the common solution that you are thinking. That is my problem:

I have an array in my state of a component(React/React Native) and I have the name of the item to get inside of the array in a variable, like this:

```
const item = [{test: 'Nhab'}];
{this.state.dataSource[0].Nhab}
```

What I would like is to change Nhab of the second line using the variable item.

This is a summary of my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
{this.state.dataSource[0][item[0].test]}
```